# PHP: Colors in var_dump (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, var-dump

I'd like to see the colors and formatting that can come with var_dump. In my `php.ini` `html_errors` is set to `On`. This is confirmed by `phpinfo()`.

My PHP version is 5.3.3 on Ubuntu 10.10. Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** Maerlyn's approach should be taken for its simplicity. I wasn't aware of  php5-xdebug being in the repos. I've decided to leave this answer because I feel it adds some value to future readers.

---

```
    sudo apt-get install php5-dev php-pear
```

Install Xdebug

```
    sudo pecl install xdebug
```

You should see something like:
`Installing '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so'` when it finishes installing. Make note of the `20090626+lfs` portion.

Edit the php.ini

```
    gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Add this to it:

```
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
```

Restart apache

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now when you do a var_dump it should be formatted, this is assuming `html_errors` is `On`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a javascript library to do the syntax highlighting. something like: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ but there are many other options as well.

Comment: Thanks but this is for a development machine and I'd really like to be able to var_dump variables in PHP without having to load additional Javascript.